# Why can't an associative Bash array be assigned with an array?

Tags: bash, associative-array

According to `man bash` it is possible to assign an associative array with a flat list of key-value pairs:

> […] or a list of words that is interpreted as a sequence of alternating keys and values: name=( key1 value1 key2 value2 ...)

This does work, but it does not work **to use an array** to get these "alternating keys and values":
`name=( "${someArray[@]}" )`

Consider this example:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -u

#declare -A map=(one ONE two TWO)
array=(one ONE two TWO)
declare -A map=("${array[@]}")
# Workaround with `eval`:
#eval "declare -A map=(${array[@]@Q})"

echo "KEYS:"
printf '    %s\n' "${!map[@]}"
echo "VALUES:"
printf '    %s\n' "${map[@]}"

echo "${#map[@]}"
```

Actual output:

```
KEYS:
    one ONE two TWO
VALUES:
```

Expected output:

```
KEYS:
    two
    one
VALUES:
    TWO
    ONE
```

Why is that so?

Comment: Although probably clear, `declare -A map=(${array[@]})` does **not** work either.

Comment: Any reference for this behaviour, @mandy8055? It also happens if assigned later, i.e. after declared.

Comment: No, it doesn't, @Amessihel. I know how to decalre an associative array. This is about using another array for doing this.

Comment: Furthermore, your claim seems to be wrong, @mandy8055: There is only a single key `one ONE two TWO`.

Comment: @doak, what's your bash version?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Using `eval` is a workaround. Not nice, though. (I've added it to the example.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Include the array parens in the quoted string to preserve the whitespace between items for the declaration. Also, if keys or values themselves contain whitespace, use `@Q` to quote each item:

```bash
array=(one 'O NE' 'tw o' TWO)
declare -A map="(${array[@]@Q})"

echo "KEYS:"
printf '    %s\n' "${!map[@]}"
echo "VALUES:"
printf '    %s\n' "${map[@]}"

echo "${#map[@]}"
```

```
KEYS:
    one
    tw o
VALUES:
    O NE
    TWO
2
```

Tested with GNU bash 5.2.21

Comment: Indeed, using `declare -A map="(${array[@]@Q})"` works. Any explanation for this? It looks like Bash is using `eval` internally for this, doesn't it?

Comment: I'd guess that `${array[@]}` is evaluated later than `declare -A map=…` is parsed. Therefore, `declare -A map=(one ONE two TWO)` is recognozed as intended whereas `declare -A map=(${array[@]})` is prematurely broken down into multiple arguments. This can be mitigated by using quotes as in `declare -A map="(${array[@]})"` or even `declare -A "map=(${array[@]})"`. The important thing is to provide two arguments to `declare`: `-A` and the "content".

Comment: U could use `declare -p map array` for showing content of `map` and `array` variable. Or even this: `paste -d '' <(printf ' - %-10s\n' "${!map[@]}") <(printf ' \47%s\47\n' "${map[@]}")`